# System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST

Tags: apex, before-trigger, standard-objects, insert, getpicklistvalues

This error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: pba.ListingTriggerDispatcher: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0C4H00000kiTQNUA2; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, valor inapropiado para el campo de lista de selección restringida: No License: [Terrace_License__c] (pba)

Comment: What about this error? Could you add what your actual question is and what you've tried so far to resolve it?

Comment: The error is telling you all you need to know. Look at what you are trying to update and make sure that it's one of the allowed values for that picklist (and recordtype)